# Noise reduction in DaVinci Resolve 14 free version

Tags: davinci-resolve, plugins, noise-reduction

DaVinci Resolve is great for hobbyists because it has a fairly capable free version. Unfortunately, the free version does not include noise reduction functionality. Are there any free tools/plugins that integrate with DaVinci Resolve on OS X and provide some sort of image noise reduction functionality?

Resolve supports OpenFX plugins.

Comment: I found [the Tuttle OpenFX suite](http://www.tuttleofx.org/), but available OS X binaries cause Resolve 14 to crash immediately.